# Applications of E8 manifold

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, intersection-theory, 4-manifolds

The $E_8$ Cartan matrix is given by,
$$
K_{E_8}=\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
-1 &  2 & -1&  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
 0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 & -1 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & 0 \\
 0 &  0 & 0 &  0 &  -1 &  0 &  0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
There is one famous application in physics. Which is that a symmetric bilinear $K_{E_8}$-Chern-Simons theory describes the low energy physics of a so-called $E_8$-quantum Hall state (with a $U(1)^8$ gauge group). The field theory partition function $Z$ is given by
$$
Z= \int[DA]\exp(\frac{(K_{E_8})_{IJ}}{2 \pi}\int A_I dA_J).
$$
This $E_8$-quantum Hall state occurs in a 2-dimensional spatial condensed matter system. This describes an **invertible TQFT**. Since the $|Z|$ on any closed 3-manifold  of $M^2 \times S^1$ has $|Z|=|\det K_{E_8}|=1$. Which means the Hilbert space on any spatial closed $M^2$ is always 1-dimensional.

The above is what I am familiar already. Now I am asking a different question about the **application of $E_8$ manifold**.

---

> My question here is that: Is there some **real-world application of $E_8$ manifold**, such as in physics or in any branch of science, or in the engineer?

The $E_8$ manifold is the unique compact, simply connected topological 4-manifold with intersection form the $E_8$ lattice.

- The $E_8$ manifold has no smooth structure.
- The $E_8$ manifold is not triangulable as a simplicial complex.
- The $E_8$ manifold is constructed by first plumbing together disc bundles of Euler number 2 over the sphere, according to the Dynkin diagram for $E_8$. This results in P$E_8$, a 4-manifold with boundary equal to the Poincaré homology sphere. Freedman's theorem on fake 4-balls then says we can cap off this homology sphere with a fake 4-ball to obtain the $E_8$ manifold.

Some refs and introductory level of explanations are welcome! Thanks.

Comment: I wonder whether any non-smoothable manifolds have any reasonably direct applications outside pure mathematics. Interesting question.

Comment: I don't know of applications of non-smooth manifolds, but there's some absolutely amazing applications of exotic smooth structures to quantum gravity by Torsten Asselmeyer-Maluga https://arxiv.org/search/gr-qc?searchtype=author&query=Asselmeyer-Maluga%2C+T

Comment: Less tongue-in-cheek, the manifold $PE_8$ you describe occurs as the resolution of a singularity of $\mathbb{C}^2/SL(2,5)$, where $SL(2,5)$ is the Binary Icosahedral group, which is the fundamental group of the Poincaré dodecahedral space. This is related to the McKay correspondence, and I had a conversation once with John Schwarz where he explained how this may be understood through ideas stemming from string theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McKay_graph